# How to paste a comma separated string over multiple cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, keyboard-shortcuts

Say I have a string of: `l,f,x,a,s,f`

I would want to paste this every comma-separated value over 6 adjacent cells. How would I do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can paste it into a split function in a cell and it will break it apart into multiple cells for you:

```
=SPLIT("l,f,x,a,s,f", ",")
```

Answer (score 251):

From https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6325535?hl=en :

- Open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
- Paste the data you want to split into columns.
- In the bottom right corner of your data, click the Paste icon.
- Click Split text to columns. Your data will split into different columns.
- To change the delimiter, in the separator box, click

PS: There is no option for 'TAB' if your text is tab-separated, you can try 4 spaces as custom separator

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 68):

You are able to paste CSV data as is into the spreadsheet and go to **Data** selecting **Split text to columns...** and even further specifying the delimiter:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

---

Also, you can simply use keyboard shortcut combo:

**<kbd>`LEFT ALT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`D`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`E`</kbd>**

---

And as already mentioned **`SPLIT`** formula:

```
=SPLIT("l,f,x,a,s,f"; ",")
```




```
=SPLIT(A1; ",")
```

For a range/array it would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A; ",")))
```

[image: 0]